# Efficent way to convert list into columns Pandas

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I have a Pandas DataFrame with the following format.

1. 2 Columns
2. Each Column has a list in each row
3. First Column has a list in each row of size 768 which is Embedding and input to a model
4. Second Column has a list in each row of size 669, each of which is a output vector with 1 at the appropriate label and 0 at others.

So the DataFrame looks something like this.

```
    embeddings                                              output_vector
0   [-0.051661342, 0.03851345, 0.039971624, -0.032...   [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, ...
1   [-0.049478885, 0.051000055, 0.02100463, 0.0374...   [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, ...
2   [0.012464094, -0.009561883, -0.015517956, -0.0...   [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, ...
3   [0.028822085, 0.010243478, -0.027818449, 0.007...   [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, ...
4   [0.011971775, -0.0076607964, 0.041782353, 0.01...   [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, ...
```

Now, I have a total of 4659904 rows. So the shape of dataframe is (4659904, 2).

I want to convert this into the following format.

```
       1           2                3     .... 768        769  770  771 ....  1437
0  0.012464094 -0.009561883 -0.015517956.... 0.34545       0    0    1          0
```

So I hope you got what I want to do.

Now I have tried 2 approaches.

1st Approach was

```
data = self.df["embeddings"].apply(pd.Series)
output = self.df["output_vector"].apply(pd.Series)

df = pd.concat([data, output], axis=1)  # first 0-767 are embeddings, next 669 are output
```

Now this was giving memory error which was

```
MemoryError: Unable to allocate 23.2 GiB for an array with shape (4659904, 669) and data type float64
```

And my second approach was

```
data = self.df['embeddings'].to_list()
output = self.df['output_vector'].to_list()
self.train = pd.DataFrame(data).astype(np.float32)
self.target = pd.DataFrame(output).astype(np.int8)
```

But this was crashing the kernel(jupyter notebook again and again. Can someone help me with an efficient solution of this.

```
Unnamed: 0,embeddings,output_vector
0,"[-0.05166134  0.03851345  0.03997162 -0.03290318  0.01512185 -0.0819034
  0.0354522  -0.02535481 -0.02994072  0.00252245 -0.05784905 -0.03258096
  0.02258191  0.00183583  0.01800507 -0.06517535 -0.04593017  0.06183863
 -0.00041441  0.03079461 -0.03463263  0.03325753 -0.04068028  0.00273206
  0.00164782  0.01204575  0.02352095  0.02062964 -0.00591917 -0.02536847
  0.04765983  0.04625681 -0.03899917 -0.02615303  0.00705981 -0.03074866
  0.05641373 -0.03783266 -0.01139919  0.03948573 -0.00663179 -0.00589749
 -0.01257528 -0.03447495  0.0518124  -0.06747232  0.01029693 -0.00407829
 -0.06775934  0.04813158  0.00797615  0.07733657  0.00468081 -0.02471192
  0.01499321 -0.00821735 -0.01809384 -0.06386615  0.021714    0.03442325
  0.05850095 -0.0393686   0.05336163  0.03389135 -0.02499526  0.01388281
 -0.02674991  0.01138506  0.01022744 -0.03536162  0.02412011 -0.02426333
 -0.0206612  -0.07695793 -0.03040081  0.08638129 -0.06665266  0.03451493
 -0.01657975 -0.00086051  0.08815629 -0.12328484  0.06338329 -0.05311166
  0.00779183  0.03247199 -0.01067247 -0.04316234  0.00292004  0.00668126
  0.06147375 -0.02413378 -0.07050701 -0.0273391   0.00202257 -0.06629693
 -0.05837518  0.01078095 -0.02034491  0.04327701 -0.04553655 -0.01302541
 -0.01778577  0.05996176  0.05047935  0.00962515  0.01945804 -0.01035258
  0.03964177 -0.05716408 -0.03015794  0.07490353  0.00869034 -0.03777959
 -0.09420589  0.04103042  0.00352532  0.00483662  0.05727965 -0.03090096
  0.01135611 -0.03559055  0.04751372  0.01635346 -0.04467079  0.01799376
 -0.04339822 -0.03085382  0.01088353  0.07680215  0.00916065 -0.0214838
  0.00708571  0.0242582  -0.01336136 -0.05095749  0.03820392  0.00641685
  0.01867483  0.02065186 -0.07288514 -0.01070622  0.01591502 -0.03233102
 -0.07069992 -0.02052268 -0.05775747  0.01626526 -0.01104282  0.03581671
  0.04181774  0.00955072  0.03185135 -0.03269299  0.02027919  0.05170641
 -0.0187701   0.01201797  0.00777477  0.02877075 -0.02029566 -0.01786695
 -0.02663675 -0.03032351  0.03577211 -0.02235947 -0.07418466 -0.0126325
  0.10378824 -0.06620239 -0.04234699 -0.01125341  0.04993306 -0.03689389
 -0.05988461 -0.01296578  0.01776955 -0.00946942 -0.00703304  0.05030575
  0.00698223 -0.03722965 -0.01775958 -0.04928617 -0.03738888  0.04596115
 -0.02617255 -0.02787984 -0.02640495  0.01742701 -0.01677947 -0.0683789
  0.02945788  0.00630781 -0.00723888 -0.06381033 -0.00552338 -0.03850625
  0.02462378  0.05535    -0.02705379 -0.05988522  0.00022431 -0.02738986
  0.0093813   0.08072495  0.02500053 -0.03987784 -0.02250899 -0.03223332
  0.06255687 -0.02878852 -0.03344632  0.00139858  0.00359832 -0.03169511
 -0.00646856  0.10101542  0.00459585  0.03286723 -0.06437351  0.01282636
  0.00808889 -0.06423829 -0.04668027 -0.01475877 -0.00268935 -0.01117125
  0.0431009   0.01491173  0.05566576 -0.02226559  0.04101704 -0.04917342
 -0.0476597   0.01837071  0.01589093 -0.02911637  0.05973773 -0.01171169
  0.03905578  0.00807729 -0.0050068   0.06247048  0.02635357  0.05955895
 -0.00128761 -0.01398617  0.00569759  0.03363681 -0.02126136  0.00090667
  0.09445269  0.00604673  0.05231062 -0.00340813  0.0390805   0.00941924
 -0.03902109  0.06293902 -0.0670393   0.05001613  0.04281409  0.02461288
 -0.00030589 -0.02006223  0.00669593  0.04665446 -0.03402932 -0.00506028
 -0.01015078 -0.05799649 -0.00326196  0.02541533 -0.03319807  0.05974461
  0.01731517  0.02651091  0.07834585 -0.03986605 -0.01025968  0.08683844
 -0.02862466 -0.01438637  0.0153399   0.00875968 -0.03147566  0.02061091
 -0.08586337  0.0597867   0.05241873 -0.0708408   0.05001192 -0.0004473
  0.05756317  0.06532589  0.08924173  0.00346854 -0.00928313 -0.00892056
  0.01053016  0.0343186   0.00204539  0.01702691 -0.04748971 -0.05348249
 -0.0029539   0.00260539  0.0098225  -0.01978774 -0.05967304 -0.0061838
  0.01658366 -0.04486167 -0.05831086  0.03481287 -0.00621805 -0.07058373
  0.01721285  0.03547975 -0.06746124  0.02165006 -0.0325329  -0.03091994
 -0.05494453 -0.00630422 -0.00797902 -0.00281971 -0.02259897  0.02063943
  0.005752    0.06251206  0.02921022  0.06215975  0.0558803  -0.00424553
 -0.01338048  0.00175178  0.00870867  0.03154808 -0.01568847 -0.00888845
  0.00431952  0.05251616 -0.03060358 -0.04899014  0.04396039 -0.02023075
  0.026639   -0.01332658 -0.00505289 -0.11766905  0.03330288 -0.06424968
 -0.03973993  0.03034413 -0.00426532  0.02609361 -0.00482141 -0.04717631
 -0.00707188  0.03314037 -0.01248469  0.06797072  0.01562233 -0.0105147
  0.00354261 -0.00955186  0.01875797  0.03931813  0.0239697   0.00619115
  0.0040127   0.0075978  -0.06994274  0.02481538 -0.00961018 -0.02109162
  0.04067701 -0.0362495  -0.01002722  0.00390972 -0.07194793  0.03292149
 -0.03827338  0.01660496  0.06368925  0.00781327  0.05230084 -0.03625728
  0.02170477  0.00077182 -0.01657453  0.00719836  0.02092477  0.01984384
 -0.00859195 -0.05363973 -0.03805922 -0.03077629  0.02392779 -0.05323811
 -0.02951413 -0.03964449  0.03160063  0.01864669 -0.00454986  0.00783485
 -0.04530802 -0.01766081 -0.03344866  0.08781784 -0.02142147  0.03471855
 -0.01810967  0.06000137  0.00132435 -0.07387639 -0.02370103 -0.04454115
 -0.00343656  0.08652093  0.02587918  0.00052981 -0.00308254  0.00107671
 -0.00158151  0.01070594  0.01756192  0.03237168  0.01560741 -0.00077113
  0.01926707 -0.00077644  0.02262588 -0.04123246  0.03067257  0.0016649
 -0.0147792   0.0135532  -0.05892413 -0.02719664  0.01523045 -0.00762503
 -0.01342774  0.02971043 -0.02252426  0.00893138  0.02293     0.03111324
  0.01178017  0.00409572 -0.01850494  0.02166766 -0.01495638 -0.04588847
  0.04611809 -0.04341035  0.03234496 -0.06332202 -0.0603806  -0.03889009
 -0.06374518  0.06303922  0.00397166 -0.0103854  -0.07204134  0.0079536
 -0.01958643 -0.00570502 -0.00287138 -0.00522236  0.02472756  0.02283627
 -0.03949913 -0.05794566  0.03683843 -0.03112188  0.00712023 -0.02576118
 -0.00179857 -0.03020315 -0.07193667 -0.01003695  0.01468337 -0.02517877
  0.07590153 -0.01844895  0.04198132  0.00439076  0.04841577  0.03099028
 -0.02027995  0.04000163 -0.00691791 -0.03516426 -0.01683368 -0.05104186
  0.02026835 -0.06700286 -0.05765624 -0.04418447  0.08306263  0.00191237
  0.08406755  0.02541559  0.0241987  -0.02964545 -0.02499546 -0.00687738
  0.03740811 -0.01796946]","[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]"
1,"[-0.04947888  0.05100005  0.02100463  0.03748612  0.07402965  0.02355377
  0.00783554 -0.00441764  0.02037947 -0.01101317 -0.07272038 -0.01317635
  0.01208586  0.03214251  0.04312667 -0.05143728  0.03066461  0.0466751
  0.03715968 -0.00359702 -0.03551948  0.00267533 -0.00440571  0.03804535
 -0.02729472  0.01140058 -0.02763288  0.04737644 -0.00771125  0.005436
 -0.01340484  0.03636687  0.0186327  -0.00719269 -0.02292635 -0.02180105
  0.02612758 -0.04786601  0.00830678 -0.00820715  0.01277367  0.00289445
  0.05075581 -0.01381035  0.10703952 -0.01868866 -0.00276579 -0.02056527
  0.00550196  0.00948418 -0.01380098  0.01052737  0.0310314  -0.07236905
  0.00497095 -0.00481839  0.03363784 -0.04349018  0.01994482 -0.04397196
 -0.00484212  0.02875007  0.09342907 -0.00678766  0.01629852 -0.02953294
 -0.00327071 -0.00457183  0.0472579   0.01426319  0.01121215 -0.02678555
  0.0221851  -0.04992006 -0.03069272  0.02178229 -0.03155816  0.05580636
 -0.0033723  -0.01350003  0.06767849 -0.08352942  0.04405996 -0.01334711
  0.0120817  -0.00189286 -0.05611677  0.03474858  0.00700947  0.00623281
  0.07472326  0.04464442 -0.01372399 -0.01544881 -0.05644816 -0.02245107
 -0.00894202 -0.02940686 -0.03199704 -0.04313582 -0.04734996 -0.00951774
 -0.01484249  0.0441848   0.02249759 -0.01967675  0.0609702  -0.04995132
  0.06243914  0.0170641  -0.08805049  0.08661282 -0.0300777   0.01642903
  0.00658593  0.02000937  0.0255114  -0.04933698  0.07683811 -0.00782323
 -0.00899224  0.03329384  0.0220267  -0.03019185  0.02728132  0.00642568
 -0.0289499   0.02845548  0.00438163  0.01891153  0.00699697 -0.0294739
 -0.0021636   0.00888361  0.03458149 -0.01702423  0.0025404  -0.05348604
  0.03069593  0.00315084 -0.04713039 -0.03305872 -0.03173357  0.04649892
 -0.04547594 -0.02613497 -0.08691893 -0.01103899  0.00898269 -0.05313889
 -0.01163842 -0.05988954  0.03866214 -0.036987   -0.01109766  0.01573566
  0.04886296 -0.05685489  0.11012544 -0.04491482  0.07410064 -0.04501069
  0.02934901 -0.07100621  0.01520117 -0.01938212 -0.05686614 -0.05348065
  0.02143558  0.00394072 -0.08290003 -0.05853761 -0.01117312  0.00471243
 -0.00375203  0.04955852  0.01673758  0.05197054  0.0216698   0.05463026
 -0.00984788 -0.02647099  0.00252488  0.03244945 -0.00879634  0.03651949
  0.00740927  0.05746639 -0.08177374  0.04510127  0.0081488  -0.02886484
  0.04043742  0.01306033 -0.00463971 -0.05626136  0.01834616 -0.11957496
  0.03398205  0.02999268  0.00874698 -0.02382371  0.00983801 -0.04475022
  0.03303507 -0.00638326 -0.01239157 -0.04301523  0.06119924 -0.07059982
  0.05701525  0.01266128  0.01218241 -0.08232405  0.02706719 -0.04054825
 -0.05780607  0.17704122  0.05719048  0.03980062 -0.03590212  0.00614331
  0.02345392 -0.00790866 -0.02183374  0.01864438  0.01037393 -0.03245463
  0.0170967  -0.01328714 -0.05193226  0.00059576 -0.06048357 -0.02022821
 -0.00310479 -0.01914704 -0.05023568  0.02727042  0.00878176 -0.02216586
  0.00938931 -0.00390131 -0.04837844  0.03407615  0.0228362   0.08055416
  0.04116102 -0.02927751 -0.00195664  0.04617704  0.00212777  0.00241917
  0.03892139  0.01910733 -0.0418299   0.02023345 -0.00865303  0.01240681
  0.00640258  0.00800394 -0.00889974 -0.03450283 -0.01890989  0.01912797
 -0.02197257 -0.07663889  0.02719502  0.01061596 -0.00026483  0.03370981
  0.03650144  0.01263927  0.01336175 -0.04579114  0.0328994   0.0248688
 -0.04855581 -0.01974464  0.03756651 -0.00639009  0.03779132  0.02220182
  0.00616892  0.01141659 -0.01113698  0.04302325 -0.03216238  0.03149698
  0.02046196  0.01607756  0.00692186 -0.0374178  -0.02151899 -0.0098618
  0.02830259  0.0264569   0.01805272  0.04347522  0.01352492  0.03655376
 -0.01035947  0.02406344 -0.01063821  0.01583334 -0.05044172 -0.02398267
 -0.05738604 -0.01207048  0.0108248  -0.00301657 -0.00202845  0.09184012
  0.03679291 -0.0312708   0.02452561  0.08745933  0.05773052  0.01184117
  0.07111108 -0.04748241 -0.01939094 -0.09380461 -0.00566202 -0.03906861
 -0.02450904 -0.02724767  0.01328717  0.01607102 -0.05773607 -0.04570262
 -0.00164463  0.05305042 -0.02471338  0.111563   -0.01652718 -0.02199577
  0.02703861  0.04213524  0.04073446  0.03265747  0.04197201 -0.01796196
  0.04649751  0.01913586 -0.04377626 -0.00598586  0.0146745  -0.00752803
 -0.01065366 -0.00598944 -0.03583477 -0.08123961 -0.02519088 -0.04696031
 -0.05836546 -0.00623604 -0.1190364   0.06981929  0.01100622 -0.00460153
  0.05733385  0.06145079  0.03309435 -0.06192654  0.01429266  0.06567662
 -0.04621225  0.05313936  0.00336892  0.0003691  -0.04774792 -0.03295233
  0.01684359  0.02263164  0.01227753  0.09997382  0.01808568 -0.0239109
  0.01934133 -0.03824954  0.02999054 -0.01835003  0.01665515  0.06795614
 -0.07662991  0.00332418  0.07094113 -0.03043634  0.01041338 -0.05544253
  0.04332612  0.02299813  0.03224237  0.01786769  0.08371793  0.03054925
 -0.04367657  0.01642182  0.00532826 -0.00530441  0.05108052 -0.02680718
 -0.00417385 -0.04220665  0.0257977  -0.05653239 -0.04292049  0.04279727
  0.04139696 -0.00987987 -0.06639605 -0.00620872 -0.03221336  0.00646489
  0.04656329  0.11048093  0.0409079  -0.05480802  0.03511234 -0.00826276
  0.06744502  0.01281725  0.01174337 -0.00049231 -0.07301029 -0.03269533
  0.06007022  0.04813014 -0.03067294  0.09440122  0.05669014  0.02734192
  0.0341919   0.01266754 -0.02646296 -0.02491366  0.01102427 -0.03399333
  0.02538971 -0.07020739  0.02144649  0.07457864  0.03454475 -0.01533873
  0.04102416  0.02037716  0.03714816 -0.05033535 -0.06547187  0.00366059
 -0.00640169  0.04219402 -0.00574962  0.00542243  0.00290861  0.03108776
  0.01167466 -0.00421096  0.03817317 -0.06365499 -0.02736501  0.00309962
 -0.04416456  0.05299811  0.02675757  0.00842932  0.00477113  0.03170447
 -0.02259091 -0.0268518  -0.03465753 -0.02036886  0.02564894  0.03522039
 -0.03034502 -0.016796    0.06861627 -0.0352925   0.0303243  -0.01676265
 -0.00409323 -0.04394965 -0.03225574 -0.01515265  0.03908413 -0.01042351
 -0.03201464 -0.08628961  0.04659296 -0.00790099  0.00291772  0.0178647
  0.02020123  0.03364336  0.007617   -0.03353637 -0.01597506  0.00604231
 -0.01836335 -0.10303532 -0.0270133  -0.04139721 -0.01958671  0.02472844
  0.04268465 -0.02371885  0.02706097 -0.0339911   0.0309197   0.00829664
  0.03402448 -0.03474662]","[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]"
```

I have added the csv of head(2) of dataframe. You can check it. It might have the list in string format, as I did df.to_csv()

Comment: Loop over the rows and make a dataframe per row and concatenate them ?

Comment: can you provide a simple copy/pastable sample dataset?

Comment: Will it be an efficient solution to loop over all the rows?

Comment: I'll edit and paste

Comment: I have added the head(2) as csv. You can check it.

Comment: Have you tried explode? If that does not kill your kernel then just transpose the df.

Comment: Your problem seems to be that you can't fit 2x the dataframe into memory, which is what most of these transposition functions roughly require. How are you loading the data?

Comment: Data is loaded via df.read_pickle as it is in pickle format.

Comment: You are probably going to have to investigate Dask for this.

Answer (score 1):

Here a simple prototype to start working on:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'embeddings': [[-0.051661342, 0.03851345, 0.039971624]]})

#                                 embeddings
# 0  [-0.051661342, 0.03851345, 0.039971624]

df2 = pd.DataFrame()
df2[['1', '2', '3']] = pd.DataFrame(df['embeddings'].tolist())

#           1         2         3
# 0 -0.051661  0.038513  0.039972
```

Comment: This also kills the kernel.

Comment: It is same as my 2nd approach.

Comment: @AhmadAnis, you can try to have a look at: http://distributed.dask.org/en/latest/memory.html which tries to make pandas fit for "big data".